# How to use google map to display location in contact us page?

Tags: google-maps

Anyone have any idea on how to use google map to display location in contact us page?

Can provide any code snippets for references?

Something like will show the pin up location in the map.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example with marker on a Stockholm Parlament: http://jsfiddle.net/g3JHD/
All you have to do is set Lat/Long of desired location to the variable `var parliament = new google.maps.LatLng(59.327383, 18.06747);`

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps offers a JavaScript API that will be able to do what you want. You simply provide the Latitude/Longitude of the location, and the map will centre on this point:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add google map with marker on contact us, please check below demo link, here you can get live demo with complete code. Please try below link :

[Google Map With Marker](http://phpwebschool.com/google-maps-with-marker/)

[image: Google Map With MArker]